# Can't make my script print output in the desired format

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pypdf

I'm trying to extract a certain portion of text from a pdf file. I've used `PyPDF2` library to do that. However, when i excecute the script below I can see that the content I wish to grab is being printed in the console awkwardly.

I've written so far:

```
import io
import PyPDF2
import requests

URL = 'http://www.ct.gov/hix/lib/hix/CT_DSG_-12132014_version_1.2_%28with_clarifications%29.pdf'

res = requests.get(URL)
f = io.BytesIO(res.content)
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
contents = reader.getPage(0).extractText()
print(contents)
```

Output I'm having:

```
ACCESSHEALTHCTConnecticutAllPayersClaimsDatabaseDATASUBMISSIONGUIDE
December5,2013
Version1.2(withclarifications)
```

Output I wish to grab like:

```
ACCESS HEALTH CT
Connecticut All Payers Claims Database
DATA SUBMISSION GUIDE
December 5, 2013
Version 1.2 (with clarifications)
```

Comment: call repr() with the bad strings and print what it returns.  that might show you what the strings really have in them.  like `print('contents =',repr(contents))`

Comment: This is what it produces when I call that `'ACCESSHEALTHCTConnecticutAllPayersClaimsDatabaseDATASUBMISSIONGUIDE\nDecember5,2013\nVersion1.2(withclarifications)'`

Comment: How about using https://github.com/GGSIPUResultTracker/ggsipu_result_extractor/blob/903116ac97992524b46b963bdbb4b2fc9e3f4d53/ggsipu_result/pdftotext.py?

Comment: Hi @Tarun, good to find you in the loop again. The thing is I'm comfortable to go for any library if that can produce desired output. However, what is important is whether I can install and run that in my machine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the link i posted, instead of having a library to depend on, you can just download the binary and call from your code, the output will be what your desire only

Comment: Could you give me a link to that binary file @Tarun? I'm little behind identifying stuffs like that. Once I download and run it from my script, I'll let you know where it leads me to.

Comment: Yes, https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [PDFMiner](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six) if installing other packages causes a dependency issue.

You can install it for python 3.7 by doing `pip install pdfminer.six`, I've already tested and its working on my python 3.7.

The code for getting page 0 is as follows

```
import io
import requests
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser

URL = 'http://www.ct.gov/hix/lib/hix/CT_DSG_-12132014_version_1.2_%28with_clarifications%29.pdf'

res = requests.get(URL)
fp = io.BytesIO(res.content)

rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
retstr = io.StringIO()
codec = 'utf-8'
laparams = LAParams()
device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

page_no = 0
for pageNumber, page in enumerate(PDFPage.get_pages(fp)):
    if pageNumber == page_no:
        interpreter.process_page(page)

        data = retstr.getvalue()

print(data.strip())
```

Outputs

```
ACCESS HEALTH CT 

Connecticut All Payers Claims Database 

DATA SUBMISSION GUIDE 

December 5, 2013 

Version 1.2 (with clarifications)
```

The good thing about PDFMiner is that it reads your pages directly and it focuses entirely on getting and analyzing text data.

Comment: Yes, it does the job perfectly. Could you please provide me with any link where I can learn more of this ` PDFMiner`?. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt they have written a [PDF](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pdfminer-docs/latest/pdfminer-docs.pdf) about it. However its very long. You could read it if you want to learn more about PDFs and how it works, but if you want general code that works you can probably search it on SO or just google it :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the issue with pyPDF2, the reason is PyPDF doesn't read newline character. Alternately you can [pdftotext](https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/)

Simple and clean, you can loop over pages or get extract one page.

```
import io
import requests
import pdftotext
URL = 'http://www.ct.gov/hix/lib/hix/CT_DSG_-12132014_version_1.2_%28with_clarifications%29.pdf'
res = requests.get(URL)
f = io.BytesIO(res.content)
pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)
print(pdf[0])
# Iterate over all the pages
# for page in pdf:
#     print(page)
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly the output I'm after but the thing is I can't install the library using `pip install pdftotext`. I'm using python 3.7.0.

Comment: because you missing the dependency here you go `sudo apt-get install build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev pkg-config python-dev`

Comment: you can check offical documentation ,clearly mentioned these `sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev pkg-config python-dev`

Comment: i'm using windows and that is the reason the library can't be installed that way. However, I made to open it using `subprocess` but can't use it in the right way. Check out [the script](https://pastebin.com/bQrEyMiy) here. How can I use it now? Thanks.

Comment: you can try this in window https://github.com/jalan/pdftotext/issues/16#issuecomment-399963100